# Node.js + Express.js + SSL

Tags: javascript, ssl, node.js, express

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set up HTTPS server in Express js (Node.js)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998694/how-to-set-up-https-server-in-express-js-node-js)

Is there a convenient way to use ExpressJS (framework for NodeJS) to handle SSL connections?

Comment: I find it weird that my post was closed when it was there first. Though I do like the answer better on the other post.

Comment: Must be frustrating, seeing as the other question got a ton of +1s, so to balance things....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd need to configure a reverse proxy (nginx, Apache). This isn't particularly Node-specific; however I haven't tried it yet so I don't know if there are any particular gotchas with Node/Express.

v0.3.4 includes an improved https module, but I believe the Express author has stated that v3, classified an unstable (odd-numbered) release, isn't supported. Of course Node's still in its infancy so instability will be the rule for some time to come.

I asked about this a few days ago:

[Node.js + SSL support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635062/node-js-ssl-support)

Comment: That's not really what I wanted to hear but it's probably a more reliable way of doing things from the sound of it.