# How to create an HTTPS server in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https, webserver

Given an SSL key and certificate, how does one create an HTTPS service?

Comment: I used [restify.js](http://mcavage.github.com/node-restify/) instead of express.js, but the idea is the same. Here's how I set up a node.js server that accepts both HTTP and HTTPS http://qugstart.com/blog/node-js/node-js-restify-server-with-both-http-and-https/

Comment: without express and with the newest version of node - look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21809393/388026

Comment: What happened to this question? The answers imply that it was originally about express.js.

Comment: it's trivial to create a valid, self-signed SSL cert and launch an HTTPS server, just a [few steps](https://github.com/75lb/local-web-server#https-server)

Comment: Its a bit late but if someone need a complete nodejs https tutorial, can find here:  http://programmerblog.net/nodejs-https-server/

Comment: This could be helpful https://contextneutral.com/story/creating-an-https-server-with-nodejs-and-express

Comment: This worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60947658/9585130

Comment: If you only want to test https://github.com/zoutepopcorn/localhapp

Answer (score 173, accepted):

For Node 0.3.4 and above all the way up to the current LTS (v21 at the time of this edit), https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#httpscreateserveroptions-requestlistener has all the example code you need:

```js
const https = require('node:https');
const fs = require('node:fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem'),
};

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('hello world\n');
}).listen(8000);
```

Note that if want to use Let's Encrypt's certificates using the [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) tool, the private key is called `privkey.pem` and the certificate is called `fullchain.pem`:

```
const certDir = `/etc/letsencrypt/live`;
const domain = `YourDomainName`;
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(`${certDir}/${domain}/privkey.pem`),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(`${certDir}/${domain}/fullchain.pem`)
};
```

Comment: `setSecure` is deprecated. Check this out instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136353/node-js-https-secure-error

Comment: See the official express answer below by @Jacob Marble.

Comment: This sample doesn't work anymore as the HTTPS implementation was re-done in Node.JS 0.4. See the corresponding docs at nodejs.org. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136353/node-js-https-secure-error?lq=1

Comment: posted an up-to-date (v0.10.x) answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21809393/388026)

Comment: This answer is very old and does not work anymore. Please see the answer by pkyeck below, or go to: http://nodejs.org/api/https.html

Comment: Also the link is broken

Comment: I know your answer was right but it does not work on my Mac, until I found this article: https://engineering.circle.com/https-authorized-certs-with-node-js-315e548354a2#.abtx7zq78 .

Comment: I had some issues whyle setting up OpenSSL certificate on my Subsystem Linux Windows, for running SSL on localhost for node.js / secure sockets, long story short, I tired out 3-5 "recepies" and the simplest and shortest one was here (10 minutes and it worked out, against 1 day of unlucky tries): https://flaviocopes.com/express-https-self-signed-certificate/ (yes it is for Mac but it worked for my Ubuntu 20 )

Answer (score 538):

The [Express API doc](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen) spells this out pretty clearly.

Additionally [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35053638/635134) gives the steps to create a self-signed certificate.

I have added some comments and a snippet from the [Node.js HTTPS documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener):

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

// This line is from the Node.js HTTPS documentation.
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.cert')
};

// Create a service (the app object is just a callback).
var app = express();

// Create an HTTP service.
http.createServer(app).listen(80);
// Create an HTTPS service identical to the HTTP service.
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

Comment: Nice, was just about to post this myself. Thank you.

Additionally, I found [this article](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server) helpful for generating a self-signed certificate.

Comment: Make sure you put `options` first in `https.createServer`, to avoid cryptic errors.

Comment: I am setting up an almost identical https server port 8888 and not sure how to change the routes. when I run curl curl --insecure https://localhost:8888
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to localhost:8888 what is the error coming from and how to get around it. When I type localhost:8888 in the browser, it hangs and https:/localhost:8888 gives SSL error

Comment: How do you force http connections through https? Can you do this through DNS, so that no one ever hits your website through plain http?

Comment: @Costa you can redirect users from http to https with [express-force-ssl](https://github.com/battlejj/express-force-ssl) or hand written middleware - it [pretty straightforward](http://jaketrent.com/post/https-redirect-node-heroku/)

Comment: Thanks, @floatdrop! So, for security reasons I'm wondering if you can eliminate the http server completely. If someone has a cookie from my site, and they hit the http server, which redirects them to the https server, that makes them vulnerable, no?

Comment: `cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem')` should be changed to `cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.crt')`

Comment: Mine says bad password read, what do I do about the key password on the cert?

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle You can disable the password: Check this [guide](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/) but if you are using macOS make sure that the generated key length is at least 2048: `openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048`

Comment: How about the case of using, var http = require('http').Server(app); rather than createServer. How could I use HTTPS then?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this creates a server with SSL handshake. Does it also take care of encrypting the responses too? what symmetric encryption is used? Should it be taken care by the server before sending the responses?

Comment: You can also use [mkcert](https://mkcert.dev) to easily set up your SSL certificates

Comment: Another good article about how to generate a self-signed certificate and set up a node server with it can be found [here](https://auth0.com/blog/using-https-in-your-development-environment/).

Answer (score 90):

Found this question while googling "node https" but the example in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5998795/388026) is very old - taken from the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html) of the current (v21) version of node, it should look like this:

````js
const https = require('node:https');
const fs = require('node:fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem'),
};

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('hello world\n');
}).listen(8000); ```
````

Comment: Worked like a charm. This information came in very handy as I run a node.js tool (PDFJS) on top of a PHP app that was recently forced to run over https. The iframe was very unhappy to load my node.js app on an alternate, non-https port.

Comment: This looks good, but how can I generate the files you are requiring there (`*.pem`)? I tried [following this page](https://freenode.net/certfp/makecert.shtml), but when opening `localhost:8000` in the browser, no data is received (just loading...).

Comment: @IonicăBizău, for generating keys, install `openssl`, then in cmd prompt, type `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 3001`

Comment: @IonicăBizău you need to directly go to `https://localhost:8080`. HTTP is NOT HTTPS.

Comment: Is it possible to create https-server with folder? So you can put file in it and access that file like https://localhost:81/main.js

Comment: @FrenkyB there is https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static that can help you with that

Answer (score 49):

The above answers are good but with Express and node this will work fine.

Since express create the app for you, I'll skip that here.

```
var express = require('express')
  , fs = require('fs')
  , routes = require('./routes');

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('cert/key.pem').toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('cert/certificate.pem').toString();  

// To enable HTTPS
var app = module.exports = express.createServer({key: privateKey, cert: certificate});
```

Comment: This seems to be deprecated since "applications no longer inherit from http.Server"

Comment: Why you setting `module.exports`? There's no need for that

Comment: @matejkramny, probably because it makes it easy to test.

Answer (score 23):

The minimal setup for an HTTPS server in Node.js would be something like this :

```js
const https = require('node:https');
const fs = require('node:fs');
    
const httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('path/to/server-key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('path/to/server-crt.pem')
};

const app = function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("hello world\n");
}
    
https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(4433);

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem'),
};
```

If you also want to support http requests, you need to make just this small modification :

```js
const http = require('node:http');
const https = require('node:https');
const fs = require('node:fs');

const httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('path/to/server-key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('path/to/server-crt.pem')
};

const app = function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("hello world\n");
}
    
http.createServer(app).listen(8888);
https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(4433);
```

Comment: All these answers are OLD and OUTDATED. I wish StackOverflow would cleanup up questions and answers that are VERY VERY OLD. `createServer` DEPRECATED! This function DOESN'T exists anymore.

Comment: What are you talking about? What do you mean `createServer` doesn't exist anymore? It's still documented in the Node.js v16.5.0 documentation in both https://nodejs.org/api/http.html & https://nodejs.org/api/https.html and not flagged as deprecated. Have you actually tried running this code? And, if so, which errors did you get?

Comment: actually I figured out my mistake. There was one line that needed changed `var https = require('https').Server(app);` to `var https = require('https');` Now, everything works... Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

### Update

Use Let's Encrypt via [Greenlock.js](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js)

### Original Post

I noticed that none of these answers show that adding a **Intermediate Root CA** to the chain, here are some **zero-config examples** to play with to see that:

- https://github.com/solderjs/nodejs-ssl-example
- http://coolaj86.com/articles/how-to-create-a-csr-for-https-tls-ssl-rsa-pems/
- https://github.com/solderjs/nodejs-self-signed-certificate-example

Snippet:

```
var options = {
  // this is the private key only
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join('certs', 'my-server.key.pem'))

// this must be the fullchain (cert + intermediates)
, cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join('certs', 'my-server.crt.pem'))

// this stuff is generally only for peer certificates
//, ca: [ fs.readFileSync(path.join('certs', 'my-root-ca.crt.pem'))]
//, requestCert: false
};

var server = https.createServer(options);
var app = require('./my-express-or-connect-app').create(server);
server.on('request', app);
server.listen(443, function () {
  console.log("Listening on " + server.address().address + ":" + server.address().port);
});

var insecureServer = http.createServer();
server.listen(80, function () {
  console.log("Listening on " + server.address().address + ":" + server.address().port);
});
```

This is one of those things that's often easier if you **don't** try to do it directly through connect or express, but let the native `https` module handle it and then use that to serve you connect / express app.

Also, if you use `server.on('request', app)` instead of passing the app when creating the server, it gives you the opportunity to pass the `server` instance to some initializer function that creates the connect / express app (if you want to do **websockets** over ssl on the same server, for example).

Comment: This is a nice explanation but, the provided link in the update section, is broken (gives 500 error)

Comment: All these answers are OLD and OUTDATED. I wish StackOverflow would cleanup up questions and answers that are VERY VERY OLD.

Comment: @ThN What isn't working for you? What's a newer, better solution?

Comment: @coolaj86 After long time of trial and turbulence (lol), I have figured out my issue. It works now. I had a line `var https = require("https").server(app);` And when I went to create server with `https.createServer(...)` I got the error message createServer not found. After changing the line to `var https = require("https");`, everything fell into place. Thank you...

Answer (score 10):

To enable your app to listen for both `http` and `https` on ports `80` and `443` respectively, do the following

Create an express app:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

The app returned by `express()` is a JavaScript function. It can be be passed to Node’s HTTP servers as a callback to handle requests. This makes it easy to provide both HTTP and HTTPS versions of your app using the same code base.

You can do so as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/cert.pem')
};

http.createServer(app).listen(80);
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

For complete detail see the [doc](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use also archive this with the Fastify framework:

```js
const { readFileSync } = require('fs')
const Fastify = require('fastify')

const fastify = Fastify({
  https: {
    key: readFileSync('./test/asset/server.key'),
    cert: readFileSync('./test/asset/server.cert')
  },
  logger: { level: 'debug' }
})

fastify.listen(8080)
```

(and run `openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout server.key -out server.cert` to create the files if you need to write tests)

Answer (score 0):

If you need it only locally for local development, I've created utility exactly for this task - https://github.com/pie6k/easy-https

```
import { createHttpsDevServer } from 'easy-https';

async function start() {
  const server = await createHttpsDevServer(
    async (req, res) => {
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.write('ok');
      res.end();
    },
    {
      domain: 'my-app.dev',
      port: 3000,
      subdomains: ['test'], // will add support for test.my-app.dev
      openBrowser: true,
    },
  );
}

start();
```

It:

- Will automatically add proper domain entries to /etc/hosts
- Will ask you for admin password only if needed on first run / domain change
- Will prepare https certificates for given domains
- Will trust those certificates on your local machine
- Will open the browser on start pointing to your local server https url