# How can I configure yeoman (gruntjs) to run as HTTPS?

Tags: https, gruntjs, yeoman

I have recently been working with Yeoman (http://yeoman.io/) and now would like to set up my local environment to handle HTTPS requests, so that I can have it handle callbacks from OAUTH providers.

Under a non-Yeoman/grunt setup I was able to get node.js configured to handle HTTPS in a following a similar path as directed in this question ([How to create an HTTPS server in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998694/how-to-create-an-https-server-in-express-js-node-js)).

Looking at the gruntJS repo on github it appears this has been added as a feature (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect/pull/15) but I still am unclear as to where I set the appropriate options.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
grunt.initConfig({
  connect: {
    server: {
      options: {
        protocol: 'https',
        port: 8443,
        key: grunt.file.read('server.key').toString(),
        cert: grunt.file.read('server.crt').toString(),
        ca: grunt.file.read('ca.crt').toString(),
        passphrase: 'grunt'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

see [this commit](https://github.com/Iristyle/grunt-contrib-connect/commit/863deb22a8e3483dce168bad2efea743f25eabd1#L1R151)