# Using https on express 4.0

Tags: node.js, express

I am aware that there is a question about using https on express 3.0, however I would like to know whether there is a new method for express 4.0. Also I am interested in why you have to declare an http server and then the https server as noted on the referenced question. Also if it matters, I am using a self signed certificate.

[Using https with express 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998694/how-to-create-an-https-server-in-node-js/14272874#14272874)

Comment: That question is not express 3.0 specific.

Comment: Does the version of express matter? the most recent accepted answer on that question was from 2011. It is probable that there is a new and better method.

Comment: Why? If you look at the answer the reason it works is because you just pass express as the callback to http.createServer , https.createServer has the same callback only you pass the certificates too.

Comment: Do you know why he even created a regular http server in the first place?

Comment: To be fair, the approved answer of the linked question is not really the best solution. But there is [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14272874/2376069) below which is totally right. `https.createServer(options, app).listen(443)` is what you need.
Regarding your second question: It's not necessary to run a second server on http, if node is behind a proxy like nginx. In this case nginx should redirect from http to https.