# Node.JS https server for Webhook gets handshake error

Tags: node.js, ssl, curl, https, webhooks

The following NodeJS just handles a webhook coming from another source. I tested it out, it works on http port 80 but the source requires https.

When I opened that port and ran this script on 443, testing it with curl gets the following error. Yet I don't think it should require a certificate should it? How would I even solve this?

`curl: (35) SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect`

Here is the script:

```
var http = require('https')

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if (req.method == "POST") {
        var str = ''
        req.on('data', function(data) {
            str += data
        })
        req.on('end', function() {
            var json = JSON.parse(str)
            res.end(json.meta.status)
        })
    }
})
console.log("HTTPS server listening on port 443...")
server.listen(443)
```

UPDATE:

Here's the latest code. I created a self-signed cert without a passphrase. I get further but I still get an error using curl with the -k option added. I get a certificate verification error without the -k.

`Cannot POST /`

```
var https = require('https')
var fs = require('fs')
var express = require('express');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.cert')
}

var app = express()

var server = https.createServer(options, app, function(req, res) {
    if (req.method == "POST") {
        var str = ''
        req.on('data', function(data) {
            str += data
        })
        req.on('end', function() {
            var json = JSON.parse(str)
            res.end(json.meta.status)
        })
    }
})
console.log("HTTPS server listening on port 443...")
server.listen(443)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS server config always requires SSL certificate. You can generate it using `openssl` here is in [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl). 
Then for node server use `crypto`,`fs` modules. Detailed config is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5998795/3961156).

Comment: This was helpful but I still can't get it working, at least not that way. It says bad password read. How do I include the password to the cert?

Comment: try to add `passphrase ` option along with `key` and `cert`. @NathanMcKaskle

Comment: there is no miracle, ok. try to use ket/cert [without passphrase](http://serverfault.com/a/366374/306011). @NathanMcKaskle

Comment: Oh I see nevermind, you linked that to creating a cert w/o a passphrase. I'll try that.

Comment: See my update to my post above.  What you said to do seems to allow the server to at least run now. Maybe I'm doing something else wrong.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle what kind of error are you getting now?

Comment: When trying curl it's saying cannot POST / see above edits to the post.

Comment: Nevermind I got it working actually. It was the express part. I'm not really using express in this webhook scenario. Not sure why that was causing this. I removed it and now I can curl without error but only if I do a -k. I gotta figure out how to do without -k. Does it have to be a legit cert?