# NodeJS Express Moongose route regex

Tags: express, mongoose, mean

I´m new to nodejs.

I have a route defined like this:

```
router.route('/sku/:id')
    .get((...args) => controllers.sku.findById(...args))
```

However, I´d like to know if there´s a way to ensure that this route only gets called if the id is a valid MongooseId. That check could be performed using:

`require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId.isValid`

I was also trying to accomplish it by using some regex, but no luck so far.

Thanks

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39220232/893780) for a regex-based method.

Comment: Thanks Tom and robert. Will check them quickly