# Can I Use An SSL Certificate On Multiple Servers?

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate, exchange-server

I have an SSL certificate from GoDaddy with multiple domains secured on it that I want to use on 3 different servers. I've installed the certificate on an Microsoft Exchange server and now I want to use it on two other servers with Node JS, but I don't know how to share it properly. The zip file I downloaded from GoDaddy included a .CRT file and .P7B file, but I think Node needs a separate private key and certificate, both in .PEM form.

Is there a way for me to convert the certificate files and share them between the servers?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can reuse the same certificate on multiple servers.

GoDaddy should have an option to download the certificates in a format that's appropriate for different web servers.  If there's an option for nginx, download those files.

You generated the private key when you created the CSR for the certificate, so you should already have that one already.  The P7B file is an intermediate certificate.  You can use https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html to convert the P7B to a PEM file.  You can then concatenate the CRT and the new PEM file into a single PEM file and use that as the certificate.

See this question on how to set that up in Node.JS: [How to create an HTTPS server in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998694/how-to-create-an-https-server-in-node-js)