# How to run node on https for windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, express, ssl, https

I have created certificates on my local machine using makecert. I can only find examples for .pem files for node, but this doesn't work for windows. How can I run https for localhost on windows using my windows based ssl files?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can only find examples for .pem files for node, but this doesn't work for windows."?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998694/how-to-create-an-https-server-in-node-js. This is just one of many. There are no working examples of how to make this work on windows. It's all for macs/linux os.

Comment: Have you tried once? I think it is same for all platform!

Comment: Yes. that is why I asked the question on here. I don't have a working solution for windows.