# How to use HTTPS on localhost:3000

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

My application requirement :

""The URL of your web form, to be displayed in a frame in the Worker's web browser. This URL must use the HTTPS protocol.""

My AWS EC2 instance has node js running on it. For some reason I am having issues running it as a production server `serve -s build`

But when I `npm start` in my project folder it runs a development server on port 3000 and I can access it via http://ec2----------.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/

But this does not work with https. Is there a way I can access the same url using https? Something like :

https://ec2----------.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/

The ways that I have looked so far : Reverse Proxy and Nginx.

But could not understand it well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTTPS server in Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998694/how-to-create-an-https-server-in-node-js)

Comment: An HTTPS connection requires a certificate, which is assigned specifically to a domain. This domain includes the port values. Amazon has licensed the certificate for port 443 on the domain `*.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Does that mean I can start my development server on 443?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1 : Choosing the Load Balancer**

The 2 choices when you create a load balancer :

**Application Load Balancer :**  If your application is running on particular ports or in dev mode or you need path-based routing. It is a good option in terms of the routing decision are done at the application layer. It can only listen from HTTP and HTTPS.

**Classical Load Balancer :** If you need to take the routing decisions right from the transport layer. You may choose one.
I will continue with the Application Load Balancer, although most of the stages are same.

**Step 2 : Configuring the Load Balancer**
Simple and quick configuration :

**Name** : Name your load balancer.

**Scheme** :

***internet facing*** : choose this if you want the requests from the client over the internet.

***internal*** : choose this if you want the requests from the client using a private IP 
             address.

**IP Address Type : ipv4**

***Listener***
A listener is a process that checks for connection requests, using the protocol and port that you configured.
There can be only two listeners in the application load balancer, which are  :

> HTTP on port 80 
>   HTTPS on port 443

**Availability Zones**

Load balancer's main job is to maintain traffic across different areas and regions. There are multiple availability zones in one region. These can be imagined as placing multiple servers in us-east These availability zones each have a separate subnet.  But only one subnet can be selected for a particular zone.

You need to select at least 2 such availability zones having distinct subnets. This basically helps the load balancer to balance the load on at least 2 servers.

**Step 3 : Configure Security Settings and Add Instance**
Configuring security settings consists of specifying the certificates if you have selected to listen to https in the previous step. Since you selected the https listener, AWS needs to use the certificate. You can learn how to get a certificate from AWS Certificate Manager. Over here you have to select :

**Certificate Type** : Choose an existing certificate from AWS Certificate Manager (ACM)

**Certificate Name :** It pops up the certificate name in the drop down list.

Select the latest security policy 
Security Policy : ELBSecurity-2016-08

Select the existing security group made for your instance.
Step 4 : Target Groups
Create a target group. Name it according to what it listens and where it targets. 
You have to mention a path and a port where the listener targets the traffic to.

**Step 5 : Deploy**

After you review the settings, deploy and create your load balancer. This will do all the cleansing and management. It is like hiring a manager for you server traffic. You can go and meditate now for some time. 
The load balancer will take almost a minute to be up and about. After the load balancer is active. Copy the DNS link of the load balancer on the main load balancer dashboard since we will need it in the next step.  It will look something like this :

```
load-balancer-name-xxxxxxxxxx.us-east-x.xxx.amazonaws.com (A Record)
```

**Step 6 : Map your domain name to the Load Balancer**

Provides a reliable and cost-effective way to route visitors to websites by translating domain names (such as www.example.com) into the numeric IP addresses (such as 192.0.2.1) that computers use to connect to each other. AWS assigns URLs to your resources, such as load balancers. However, you might want a URL that is easy for users to remember. For example, you can map your domain name to a load balancer.

Go to Route 53 and select the hosted zone and the record set for your domain name.

```
You need to create a new record : 
1) Leave the domain name blank. 
2) Select Yes for Alias.
3) Paste the DNS link for the Load Balancer in the Alias Target.
4) Create.
```

This step is basically a transfer of risk. It routes the domain name to the dns of the load balancer. Hence solves our purpose of handling traffic. The rest of the job is handled by the ELB, which translates its statistics into the health reports, based on which you can create and replace more instances.

Have a great one!

Citation : https://sites.google.com/gwmail.gwu.edu/aws-tools/aws-elastic-load-balancer?authuser=0

Answer (score 1):

If you use an elastic load balancer in front of the EC2 instance then AWS provides a very easy way to get HTTPS working. If you want to access the instance directly you will need to configure HTTPS in your node.js or use an HTTPS service to proxy the traffic to your node.js app.

Comment: In the first case, I am using the public dns, do I choose 'upload a ssl certificate'? And second case I'm trying to do that. Thanks. I'll accept as soon as it works.

Comment: You can create one with the AWS Certificate Manager for use in ELB. I don't think there is a charge if it's used on AWS resources. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ssl-server-cert.html

Comment: You need a domain for it. I do not have a domain. I am using the public dns of the ec2 instance to access my website.

Comment: If you are using that then you would either need to support HTTPS in the node.js app, use an intermediate layer like nginx with ssl termination. You would still require a certificate for the dns name used though. Other alternatives are to use Elastic Beanstalk to deploy as it configures ELB and nginx for you, use CloudFront as it comes with HTTPS support on cloudfront.net domains or register for your own domain in Route53.

Comment: Yes, I took your point and registered a domain. https://sentien.tech and works for me now. I route the https request on port 3000. I also blogged about here : https://sites.google.com/gwmail.gwu.edu/aws-tools