# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH in node js

Tags: node.js, ssl, server, tls1.2

I recently purchased a personal ssl certificate from Positive ssl. After i got everything sorted out with activating it and the validation, I was finally able to download the certificate files.

The files i got were:

```
www.niknet.ddns.net.ca-bundle
www.niknet.ddns.net.crt
www.niknet.ddns.net.p7b
```

Before I only used `.key` and `.crt`
and it worked great but now i am using the `.ca-bundle` and the `.crt` file
this is the code i use to include those files into the ssl library in node js

```
var httpPort = process.env.PORT || 80;
var httpsPort = process.env.PORT || 443;
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(httpPort);
var server = https.createServer({
    secureProtocol : 'TLSv1_2_server_method',
    ciphers : "AES128-GCM-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH",
    honorCipherOrder : true,
    ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/niknet_ddns_net.ca-bundle'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/niknet_ddns_net.crt')

    },app).listen(httpsPort);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

but I can't for the life of me get the certificate to work properly.
I just get this error

```
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

I've been reading other posts and have tried adding their code but nothing works.
I also read somewhere that the ssl or tls library for node.js is outdated and that my certificate could be too new. If that's true, are there any other third-party ssl libraries I could use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTTPS server in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998694/how-to-create-an-https-server-in-node-js)

Answer (score 7):

run this command:

```
openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout server.key -out server.cert
```

Just remember to set this to localhost:

`Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:` localhost

then

```
 https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server.cert')
  },app)
```

`ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH` will appear if the added certificate are not indicated properly in the first argument of `createServer()`.

Comment: Thank you, worked for me. Had to add also a "const fs = require('fs');" line over the "https.createServer..." to declare the fs const... Hope It helps someone :)

Answer (score 2):

tested key and crt with openssl using bellow command (try in browser https://hostname:8888).. and found the exact cipher missing.

`openssl s_server -cert server.crt -key server.key -CAfile octopz.zende.sk.ca-bundle -accept 8888 -www`

Then added to the nodejs code.

```
var server = https.createServer({
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate,
    ca: certificateAuthority,
    ciphers: [
        "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256",
        "DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256",
        "AES128-GCM-SHA256",
        "RC4",
        "HIGH",
        "!MD5",
        "!aNULL"
    ].join(':'),
}, app);
```

it worked!!

Answer (score 1):

We have lots of dupes of this for other languages, but the closest I can find for nodejs is [How to create an HTTPS server in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998694/how-to-create-an-https-server-in-node-js) which is not specific or [ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH with node v7.9.0 https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46229995/err-ssl-version-or-cipher-mismatch-with-node-v7-9-0-https) which is not answered. So:

SSL/TLS server including **an HTTPS server needs a privatekey AND certificate/chain** (with rare exceptions not applicable here). You can use a CA-issued cert (and chain) instead of a self-created (and usually self-signed) cert, as long as the CA-issued cert is for the same privatekey, but **you must still provide the privatekey**. You can use `cert` and `key` together, or you can combine the cert (and optionally chain) and key into a PKCS12-also-called-PFX file, and use `pfx`.

In addition to the Q you asked, and arguably offtopic for SO, don't use RC4. It's considered broken cryptographically, though still on average moderately difficult/costly in practice, and most standards for using SSL/TLS/HTTPS prohibit it for several years now, particularly [rfc7465](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7465).