# Very basic https server

Tags: node.js

I created a http server and everything works fine.

But I actually want to create a https server instead. I don't care about security because this is just for testing.

How can I expose my data from https instead of http?

Is this something easy to do? Any idea how can I do this very easily?

```
   "use strict";

     var http = require("http");
     var fs = require("fs");

     var port = 5050;

var cors = function cors(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
        return;
    }
};

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    // simulate SEND to IPP Process
    if(request.method === 'PUT') {
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': request.headers.accept });
        response.end();
        return;
    }

    if (request.headers.origin) {
        cors(request, response);
    }

    var fileName = request.url.substr(request.url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    if(fileName !== 'favicon.ico') {
        fileName = fileName === 'inData' ? 'all' : fileName;
        try {
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': request.headers.accept});
            var res = '';
            if(request.headers.accept === 'application/xml') {
                res = fs.readFileSync('mock/data/'+fileName+'.xml');    
            } else if (request.headers.accept === 'text/plain') {
                res = fs.readFileSync('mock/data/'+fileName+'.txt');
            } else {
                if(fileName.indexOf('?') !== -1) {
                    fileName = fileName.substr(0, fileName.indexOf('?'));
                }
                res = fs.readFileSync('mock/data/'+fileName+'.json');
            }

            response.write(res);
        } catch (e) {
            console.warn(e.message);
            response.writeHead(400, {});
        }

        response.end();
    } else {
      response.writeHead(400, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
      response.end();
    }

});

server.listen(port);
console.log("Server is listening at http://localhost:"+port);
```

Comment: `require("https")` :) Easy enough

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTTPS server in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998694/how-to-create-an-https-server-in-node-js)