# Running Node with HTTPS

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I have created a vue cli 3 project.  To run it, I call 'npm run serve'. This is an alias in package.json to "vue-cli-service serve".

Where do I inject code to make the site use HTTPS?  I see tons of code showing 'how' to do it (Ex [How to create an HTTPS server in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998694/how-to-create-an-https-server-in-node-js)), but I am not understanding WHERE to put that code and how to call it when I run 'npm run serve'

Comment: Isn't the "modern" solution to put your apps behind a proxying server like Nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `vue.config.js` beside `package.json` in your project directory

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    https: true
  }
}
```

Vue-Cli uses the [webpack dev server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-https) which has the `https` option.