# http to https url in AWS Beanstalk single instance environment

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed my `NodeJS/Express` app on `AWS Beanstalk`. The current config is :

```
Environment type: single instance
EC2 instance type: t2.micro
Node.js version: 10.15.0
No load balancer
Proxy server : Nginx
```

When deployed it gives me a URL `http://<app-name>.<server-location>.elasticbeanstalk.com/`

I tested (using `Postman`) my authenticate API with the URL - `http://<app-name>.<server-location>.elasticbeanstalk.com/users/authenticate` and it gives me the status code of `200 OK` and is working fine.

**When I use HTTPS instead of HTTP it doesn't work as expected**. In postman I get below error:

```
There was an error connecting to https://<app-name>.<server-location>.elasticbeanstalk.com/users/authenticate
```

I have my frontend deployed on netlify and when I trigger the same request from my Web application it gives me below error :

```
The page at 'https://<app-name>.netlify.com/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://<app-name>.<server-location>.elasticbeanstalk.com/users/authenticate'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I understand that since my request is coming from https I need to have my backend configured to have https listener. I am not sure as to how I can accomplish this in AWS Beanstalk where I don't have a Load balancer and my env type is a single instance.

I am new to AWS. Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998694/how-to-create-an-https-server-in-node-js

Comment: Thanks. I read the solution but it requires changes in my node application. Can't I have it somehow configured on my server like in this case AWS Beanstalk.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add an .ebextension config file to:

- Allow 443 traffic in your Security Group
- Install the ssl package
- copy the certificates from the application package to the ssl dir. (certificates can be created in the certificate manager) or paste them in the config file
- edit nginx config

Here is an example
https://edwardsamuel.wordpress.com/2015/07/17/enable-https-and-http-redirect-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: Thanks. But after reading the solution what I understand is that they are using ELB load balancer. I don't have any load balancer in my application as it is single env basic application.

Comment: You can cut out the loadbalancer parts. It should work.