# Forge app can run on localhost but result cannot be loaded in browser

Tags: autodesk-forge

Server listening on port 3000

http://localhost:3000/ works OK until now, anyone knows the reason and how to fix it? thanks

telnet 127.0.0.1 3000 seems OK, is it because security setting?
[image: screen capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a Forge issue actually... Anyway

Please check if your localhost is redirected to `https://` while connecting with `http://`. If it is, there are two ways to prevent it happens again:

1. Open the website in the incognito mode.
2. Change the hsts setting for localhost on your machine: https://superuser.com/a/881431

Otherwise, you need to check your local HTTP server's SSL settings to get rid of this problem.

Comment: thanks Eason, yes, it's redirected to https://, it's fixed only after i restart computer.

Comment: but what if i do want using https://, i will get ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, by turning off "Use SSL 3.0" at Internet setting will fix the issue? i knew it's not Forge issue, you may ignore my question, thanks again Eason!

Comment: It's something related to your backend server. Not sure which one you're using. In C#, we can do something like this: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/developing-locally-with-aspnet-core-under-https-ssl-and-selfsigned-certs

Comment: i'm using node js at this moment, only use c# for Revit API, well, perhaps due to security setting by strict IT policy, thanks Eason.

Comment: if it's nodejs, check this thread :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14272874/7745569